# Strategy or technique for tracking and displaying NAV over time

Tags: historical-analysis

Does anyone know of a strategy or technique for displaying NAV (Net Asset Value) over time for individual funds? I'm very familiar with Google Sheets (Excel), but I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: What on earth could be off-topic to PF about an individual trying to do his own technical analysis?  (Sure, the info can become obsolete at some point, but **not now**.  Which is why I think that's a bad rule.)

Comment: @RonJohn It's product/service recommendation questions that are off-topic. Technical analysis questions are not specifically off-topic. More discussion [at meta](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/what-is-meant-by-the-off-topic-close-reason-product-or-service-recommendations).

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea people are voting it off-topic, and I don't understand why.  According to https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic questions about "Investing and trading strategies, **including fundamental and technical analysis** and other techniques" are most certainly on-topic.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea and `Mr. B`  most certainly falls under the category of "retail traders and investors", because otherwise he wouldn't be asking about free chart tools.

Comment: @RonJohn You're misunderstanding. Forget about technical analyis for a moment. What makes this question off-topic is that it is **seeking a product/service recommendation**. It doesn't matter that technical analysis is on-topic. *All* questions that ask for a product/service recommendation are off-topic. They become magnets for spam, astroturfing, etc. Notice *"Use of software for managing one's finances. (**Not recommendations**, just questions regarding specific software)"* at the same page you linked to.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea that's throwing the baby out with the bathwater.  (Though than analogy might get me accused of misogyny.)

Comment: @RonJohn Perhaps. Best to discuss at the meta post I linked earlier.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea The solution doesn't have to be a "product or service". The solution could be instruction on developing a spreadsheet that charts the NVA over time and/or pulls in the data from an publicly available API that I'm not aware of. 

If the link to the charting tool is the problem, I'll gladly remove it.

Comment: @MrB It's not the inclusion of the chart service link in your question that's at issue -- it's the asking for a product/service recommendation to replace it. You could certainly edit your question, but bear in mind that asking for a public data API recommendation is the same as asking for a chart service recommendation -- a recommendation request.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Does the edit work? If yes, please unlock. Thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for advanced plotting of data is Mathematica, assuming that you have the time to learn how to use it. Mathematica has [a basic tutorial on plotting financial data](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FinancialVisualization.html). You can hook Mathematica up to [dynamic feeds of financial data](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html).

The basic function for plotting time-series values, like NAV, in Mathematica is the [DateListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html) function, but there are other specialized plots (listed previously above) specifically for financial time series.

Answer (score 0):

Categorised by investment platform in this example.

[image]

Source: https://www.pallinghurst.com/nav-eps/